# how to make button Buy Now for opencart?

Tags: opencart, checkout

I'm using opencart 2.1.0.1, and use theme default .
I see at opencart inconvenience because it doesn't has button "Buy Now" skip add to cart.
Every body please help me, how to make button Buy Now for opencart
thanks you!

Comment: What exactly are you expecting "Buy Now" to do?  Do you just want to redirect to checkout after adding the item to cart?

Comment: yes simple just want redirect to checkout after click buy now button ( add button)

Answer (score 1):

To change the button text edit `catalog/language/english/english.php` where it says:

```
$_['button_cart']           = 'Add to Cart';
```

If you are using multiple languages, edit other paths accordingly.

To redirect to cart you can edit the file: `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl` and look around line 466 to find this:

```
if (json['success']) {
    $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

    $('#cart > button').html('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total']);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
}
```

Change it to add a redirect and comment out the other stuff like this:

```
if (json['success']) {
    window.location.href = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    //$('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
    //$('#cart > button').html('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total']);
    //$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    //$('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
}
```

If you want this to work in category and search lists you need to make the same edit in `/catalog/view/javascript/common.js` around line 153.